# Get flickr photos with YQL with multiple parameters

Tags: apache-flex, filter, air, flickr, yql

I'm trying to create a Flex app to get photos from flickr(using YQL) of "something" near a given ZIPCODE and ordered by interestigness.

I can't figure out how. I'm on http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ and i see that there are different tables: flickr.photos.search, flickr.photos.interestigness etc.I guess i have to make an  sql join in order to filter the photos but i dpn't know what columns they contain.

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key table to search on is `flickr.photos.search`, which allows you to search photos with numerous filters and to sort the results by interestingness as you want.

A simple query which searches photos within a 20km radius of Beverly Hills, CA, USA for the word "hill" and orders the results by interestingness might look like the following.

```
select * from flickr.photos.search where 
    has_geo="true" and text="hill" and sort="interestingness-desc" 
    and radius="20" and radius_units="km" and place_id in (
        select place_id from flickr.places(1) where query="90210, USA"
    )
```

<sup>[» Try this in the console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20flickr.photos.search%20where%20has_geo%3D%22true%22%20and%20text%3D%22hill%22%20and%20sort%3D%22interestingness-desc%22%20and%20radius%3D%2220%22%20and%20radius_units%3D%22km%22%20and%20place_id%20in%20%28select%20place_id%20from%20flickr.places%281%29%20where%20query%3D%2290210%2C%20USA%22%29)</sup>

---

> i dpn't know what columns they contain.

When using the console, each table *should* have an associated URL pointing to the documentation for the service that that table provides.  That link, and other information about the table (e.g. required parameters), can be found by executing a query of the form `desc <table name>`.  For example, the query `desc flickr.photos.search` in the YQL console shows:

[image: XML result for: desc flickr.photos.search;]

That `documentationURL` ([here](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html)) takes you to Flickr's documentation page for the `flickr.photos.search` API method, which shows all of the available parameters that can be used. You'll see descriptions for the `where` clause parameters from the YQL query we used to search for photos near Beverly Hills.